# How to get a names List of collections indexed in a collection, in firebase in Flutter?

Tags: http, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I have the next datas on real time firebase database:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl3gz.jpg)

As you see, there are more data in "animals" , "rocks" and "vegetables". I want get that names in a List of data, something like this:

```
List list = ["animals","rocks", "vegetables"];
```

I know how to do a get http request in flutter to get data doing this:

```
var response =  await http.get('https://mydb.firebaseio.com/prueba.json');
pruebaFirebase = json.decode(response.body);
```

But it returns a List of collections, and I only need the name of each one names of collections.

Thanks in advance dear community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [shallow](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-param-shallow) query parameter of the Realtime Database REST API:

```
https://mydb.firebaseio.com/prueba.json?shallow=true
```

Comment: Good night Doug, thank you for reply.
With that, I got this JSON:

```
{animals:true, rocks: true, vegetables: true}
```
I tried to use that data but I couldn't. I tried to transform it to a LIST with

pruebaFirebase = json.decode(response.body) as List;

But it dind't run. Do you know a way to solve it?

Thanks in advance, Doug.